# How many surjective functions satisfies the given property?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I've been struggling on this problem for quite a bit and was wondering if someone could help me.
The question goes as follows:
$X$ is a finite set with $|X|=n$ and $n$ is a odd number. How many surjective functions $f:X\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ are they with the property: $$|f^{-1}(0)|<|f^{-1}(1)|$$
If someone knows the answer please tell me how you got to your answer so I can understand it.

My thougts: I thougth of $arcsin(x)$ because $arcsin(0)$ < $arcsin(1)$, and $arcsin(x)$ is a inverse function, but how could I possibly find all functions?

Thanks in advance :)

PS: could someone also explain to me what they exactly mean with $|X|=n$, do they just mean absolute value?

Comment: $|X|=n$ means that the set $X$ has $n$ elements. For example, if $X=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, then $|X|=n$.

Comment: $\vert X \vert$ stands for the cardinality of the set $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|X|=n$ just means that there are $n$ elements in $X$.

Note that for any surjective function $f:X\to2$ ($2$ is the set $\{0,1\}$), either $$|f^{-1}(0)|<|f^{-1}(1)|$$or vice versa, since $n$ is odd, and $$|f^{-1}(0)|+|f^{-1}(1)|=n$$And, for any surjective function $f$, $g(x)=1-f(x)$ is also a surjection $X\to2$, and it satisfies the property iff $f$ doesn't

In other words, this implies that exactly half of all surjective functions $X\to2$ have the property. There are $2^n-2$ surjective functions from $X\to 2$ (since there are only $2$ non surjective functions), and hence, $2^{n-1}-1$ surjective functions with the property you asked for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand why you can say $$|f^{-1}(0)|+|f^{-1}(1)|=n$$, or why $g(x)=1-f(x)$  (is that a rule). And how do you know that there are $2^{n-1}-1$ surjective functions using your logic. Srry that I have so much questions but I really want to know

Comment: $1$. That sum equals $n$ because all $n$ elements of $X$ map to either $0$ or $1$, so they are counted in either $f^{-1}(0)$ or $f^{-1}(1)$. $2$. It's not a rule, just a function I constructed to show that exactly half of the surjective functions satisfy your property. $3$. You need to read the answer a bit more carefully.